# Python error: invalid literal for int()

Tags: python

I am new to python. I am writing a script to pull some data from website and graph it. However, my code is erroring out, saying that the data types aren't correct. Specifically, I have both decimal values for 'value' and dates for 'year'. I tried to redefine them but I think I'm putting the definition in the wrong place. Any help would be appreciated, the code is below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import json
import matplotlib.pyplot as mp
from IPython.display import HTML
import getpass
import requests

def frame(url, height=400, width=100):
    display_string = '<frame src={url} width={w} height={h}>
                      </iframe>'.format(url=url, w=width, h=height)
    return HTML(display_string)

frame('https://data.bls.gov/registrationEngine/')
registration_key = getpass.getpass('Enter Registration Key: ')

series = 'MPU4900012'

frame('https://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v1/timeseries/data/')

def capture_series(series, start, end, key=registration_key):
    url = 'https://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v2/timeseries/data/'
    url += '?registrationkey={key}'.format(key=key)

    data = json.dumps({
        "seriesid": [series],
        "startyear": str(start),
        "endyear": str(end)
    })

    headers = {
        "Content-type": "application/json"
    }

    result = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
    return json.loads(result.text)

json_data = capture_series(series, 1987, 2016)
json_data

df_data = pd.DataFrame(json_data['Results']['series'][0]['data'])
print(df_data)

df_sub = df_data[['value', 'year']].astype(float).astype(int)
df_sub.set_index('year', inplace=True)
df_sub.sort_index(inplace=True)
df_sub

x = df_sub.index
y = df_sub['value']

mp.plot(x,y)
mp.title('Major Sector Multifactor Productivity')
mp.xlabel('years')
mp.ylabel('values')
mp.show
```

When I run the code, I first get this table, which is the site data.

```
footnotes period periodName   value  year
 0      [{}]    A01     Annual  86.244  1996
 1      [{}]    A01     Annual  84.713  1995
 2      [{}]    A01     Annual  85.141  1994
 3      [{}]    A01     Annual  84.688  1993
 4      [{}]    A01     Annual  85.037  1992
 5      [{}]    A01     Annual  82.280  1991
 6      [{}]    A01     Annual  82.625  1990
 7      [{}]    A01     Annual  81.965  1989
 8      [{}]    A01     Annual  81.587  1988
 9      [{}]    A01     Annual  80.816  1987
```

The error log shows this (using Jupyter w/ Python 3 for reference)

```
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-101-8ee6d83ca777> in <module>()
     41 print(df_data)
     42 
---> 43 df_sub = df_data[['value', 'year']].astype(int)
     44 df_sub.set_index('year', inplace=True)
     45 df_sub.sort_index(inplace=True)

     ...

     ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '86.244'
```

Comment: Can you post the error log?

Comment: What does `print(df_data[['value', 'year']])` show?

Comment: The ValueError is saying that you're trying to cast '86.244' to integer. The cast should be to float.

Comment: Yes, also, looks like the `DataFrame` is constructed from `JSON`, seeing as you are using requests. Decimal numbers in `JSON` will always be a `str`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I had a play with your example.

I think the `value` column is a `str` type. Which means you need to use `.astype(float)` first.

Here:

```
>>> data = {'value': {0: '84.713', 1: '85.141', 2: '84.688', 3: '85.037',
        4: '82.280', 5: '82.625', 6: '81.965', 7: '81.587', 8: '80.816'}, 
        'year': {0: '1995', 1: '1994', 2: '1993', 3: '1992', 4: '1991',
         5: '1990', 6: '1989', 7: '1988', 8: '1987'}}

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df
    value  year
0  84.713  1995
1  85.141  1994
2  84.688  1993
3  85.037  1992
4  82.280  1991
5  82.625  1990
6  81.965  1989
7  81.587  1988
8  80.816  1987

>>> df['value'].astype(int)  # <- replicating eror
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '84.713'

>>> df['value'].astype(float).astype(int)  # <= HERE
0    84
1    85
2    84
3    85
4    82
5    82
6    81
7    81
8    80
Name: value, dtype: int32
```

**So use:**

```
df[['value', 'year']].astype(float).astype(int)
```

Comment: Hi @James Schinner, you're right, I didn't realize your could append multiples of astype() to the data frame, and adding in .astype(float).astype(int) worked. I've edited the code in my question to show the changes. Thanks for your help!